# Using the set function with indexes as keys in Ember

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I can't figure out how to use the Ember.set functionality in Ember.JS with indexes. For now I have been using the following code to make this functionality:

```
this.get('array')[index1][index2].value = value.target.value;
```

But this keeps giving the following error:

```
ember.debug.js:16664 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `value` property (of [object Object]) to `xxx`.
```

I imagine the solution should look something like this:

```
this.set('array'[index1][index2], value.target.value);
```

Howerever, I have tried quite a few different forms of the solution above and none of them seems to work.

An example of the array looks like this:

`matchingArray: [
    [{
      "property":  'pathname',
      "variable": null,
      "equal": true,
      "operator": 'equals',
      "value": null
    }]
  ]`

I am using Ember v1.13 with Node v4.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below,

```
var k = this.get('matchingArray');
Ember.set(k[index1][index2],'value','Success');
```

sample [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7fc2399bf76c06598174f8891c7037e8?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 0):

If the array is an array of objects then you can use the following code:

```
this.get('array.index1').index2 = new_value;
```

If the array is an array of models then you can use:

```
this.get('array.index1').set('index2', new_value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the solution is not targeting the specific value as seen in the first code example: `this.get('array')[index1][index2].VALUE = value.target.value;`. Do you know how to change that specific value?

Comment: Can you please post a sample structure of the array ?